# Get entity object from CommandArgument in GridView RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using a `GridView` which is bound to a `List<Customer>`.  When `RowCommand` is fired by some button I want to be able to retrieve the current row's `Customer` object from the `e.CommandArgument`, like so:

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = (Customer)e.CommandArgument;
    DoSomething(customer);
}
```

How do I assign the `Customer` object to `CommandArgument` before the event is fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can actually store a complex object in the CommandArgument as it seems to only take string or numeric values.

Something, which I have never really put into practice, is to convert your object into a Json string and use this as your command argument.

For example, using Newtonsoft.Json and a dummy object called `FooBar`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" 
CommandName="Click" 
CommandArgument='<%#Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject((FooBar)Container.DataItem) %>' 
Text="Click" />
```

Then when you handle the GridView RowCommand click event, you can Deserialize the object from the CommandArgument

```
FooBar fooBar = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooBar>(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Now this works, but whether it is the best solution, I am not sure.